# Access Guzzle Response from Goutte

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

I'm trying to access to the Guzzle Response object from Goutte. Because that object has nice methods that i want to use. getEffectiveUrl for example.

As far as i can see there is no way doing it without hacking the code.

Or without accessing the response object, is there a way to get the last redirected url froum goutte?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little late, but:

If you are only interested in getting the URL you were last redirected to, you could simply do

```
$client = new Goutte\Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.example.com');
$url = $client->getHistory()->current()->getUri();
```

EDIT:

But, extending Goutte to serve your needs is fairly easy. All you need is to override the createResponse() method and store the GuzzleResponse

```
namespace Your\Name\Space;

class Client extends \Goutte\Client
{
    protected $guzzleResponse;

    protected function createResponse(\Guzzle\Http\Message\Response $response)
    {
        $this->guzzleResponse = $response;

        return parent::createResponse($response);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Guzzle\Http\Message\Response
     */
    public function getGuzzleResponse()
    {
        return $this->guzzleResponse;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the response object as desired

```
$client = new Your\Name\Space\Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/redirect');
$response = $client->getGuzzleResponse();

echo $response->getEffectiveUrl();
```

Comment: Yes, i found this too. This is the only way to get the last redirect url as far as i know. But i want to access the Guzzle response too.

Comment: I have added an easy way of extending Goutte for your needs. Hope it helps.